# calculating a circle

Tags: php, geometry

I did this but I can't see the PHP part when I tried to view it on Internet Explorer.

This is the code I did:

```
<html>
<head><title>Practise</title></head>
<body>

<form method="post">
Circumference of a Circle or the Area: <br>

The Radius of the circle: <input type="text" name="radius"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">    

<?php

$rad = (float) $_POST['radius']; 
$cir = $rad * 2 * pi();
$area = pow($rad, 2) * pi();

echo "The circumference of the circle is:" $cir.; 
echo "The area of the circle is:" $area.;  
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Please state the wrong code. Thank you!

Comment: @Edo: please edit your question, paste the real code, select it, and click on the `{}` button in the editor. It will produce readable code and html.

Answer (score 1):

The two echo lines should be:

```
echo "The circumference of the circle is:".$cir; 
echo "The area of the circle is:".$area;
```

The concatenation operator (point) goes between the strings you want to merge.

Your current code isn't executed because of a syntax error.

Comment: @Edo: great! You might want to accept my answer (or passcod's, or John Green's - they all addressed the same issue).

Answer (score 1):

Well first you got string concatenation wrong:

```
$result = "String " $var.;  // Wrong
$result = "String " . $var; // Right
$result = "String $var";    // Right too.
$result = "String ", $var;  // Also right.
```

Then you should really do some input checking:

```
if (!empty($_POST['radius']) {
  // ...
}
```

There's also a closing `</form>` tag missing, as well as the `action="..."` attribute on the `<form>` tag -- although this should default to the page itself.

And finally it's 'Practice', not 'Practise'... :)

Comment: Why "practice"? Both "practice" (noun) and "practise" (verb) are correct. `</form>` is missing though, and form's `action` attribute is missing. As for displaying strings, `echo "string", $var;` can also be used.

Comment: Didn't know about that third form. Edited your comments in.

Answer (score 0):

This is better:

```
...
<form method="post" action="this-page.php">

Circumference of a Circle or the Area: <br />

The Radius of the circle: <input type="text" name="radius" /> <br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>

<?php

if (array_key_exists("radius", $_POST)) {

    $rad = (float) $_POST['radius'];
    $cir = $rad * 2 * pi();
    $area = pow($rad, 2) * pi();

    echo "The circumference of the circle is: $cir.";
    echo "The area of the circle is: $area.";
}
?>
...
```

Comment: Except for the extra parens (and, imo, the abhorrent practice of using PHP's string expansion and use of isset() instead of array_key_exists() -- bot those arguments are off-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Your echos are broken:

```
echo 'The circumference of the circle is:'.$cir.'.'; 
echo 'The area of the circle is:'.$area.'.';
```